# How to set ToString("00") for hours/minutes/seconds when changed on button click

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF App where I have a Timer, I did everything accept how to when the numbers of hours/minutes/seconds are changing on button click, they should stay in this format: 01, 02, 03 etc. and by me it's 1, 2, 3 etc.

here is my code for hours Up and Down click:

```
private void btnHoursPlus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            int number = Convert.ToInt32(tbHours.Text);
            if (number < 24)
            {
                tbHours.Text = $"{number + 1}";
            }
        }

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------


private void btnHoursMinus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(tbHours.Text);
            if (number > 0)
            {
                tbHours.Text = $"{number - 1}";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the number of digits when converting to a string.

```
tbHours.Text = $"{number - 1:D2}";
// result 01, 02, 03 ...
```

More information can be found in the Decimal entry on the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings).

Comment: Note. This isn't the WPF/MVVM way to achieve what you want. Ideally, you should have converters to convert the value from the model bound value. The model should be in the domain driven type (this case, `TimeOnly`, rather than `string`).